# What are possible reasons for a DNA template not giving amplification?

Tags: pcr, primer

I am trying to amplify ~10kb length fragments using NEB LongAmp Master Mix. I had been using one particular aliquot of DNA (template amount in each PCR reaction of 10ul being around 60ng) and getting amplification results as desired. However, when I switched to a different aliquot of similar concentration, I am not getting amplification all of a sudden. I tried a different DNA sample and different primers and got results. So the problem lies with either the template or the primers. I have tried increasing amount of template, increasing Mg<sup>2+</sup> by 1mM in the final reaction etc. but to no avail. The DNA templates/100x primer stocks are stored at -20⁰C and the DNA had been phenol-chloroform extracted. What could possibly be wrong here ?

Comment: When you changed only the DNA you use it is pretty likely the reason. How do you prepare this DNA? Was there anything different than in the batch before?

Comment: No. I had extracted it using Phenol Chloroform method and had the original DNA concentration at 700ng/ul. From this, I used 1 part DNA and 9 parts RNA free water dilutions to use for PCR. When I made a new batch of such dilutions recently, I am not getting any amplification.

Comment: A new batch of dilution or a new batch of DNA which was diluted this way? From what tissue or cells do you extract the DNA?

Comment: Possible problems:

 1. Degraded primers: What were they dissolved in. Run a 10% PAGE in 0.5x TBE to see if they are fine
 2. Degraded template: Check on gel. 100ng is sufficient to see on the gel.

Comment: When doing the phenol chloroform extraction, are you doing a chloroform only extraction to remove leftover phenol? Are you sure you're only taking the aqueous layer? If you're pulling phenol or chloroform into your aliquot of DNA those could interfere with the enzymes.

Answer (score 2):

Lets summarize the comments into a real answer: When the only chemical changed in your reaction is the DNA, which came from a fresh Phenol/Chloroform preparation, I would suspect it. From there, we have a few possibilities, what could have gone wrong.

1. The most likely cause of an enzymatic reaction not working with
   Phenol/Chloroform prepared DNA are left-overs (or carry-over) of the
   organic solvents from the reaction. The inhibit (especially Phenol)
   enzymatic reactions very efficiently. It would help to do another
   round of DNA precipitation.
2. It is possible that your DNA didn't got dissolved after the drying
   step in the precipitation. Depending on the conditions, DNA can form
   a pellet which is hardly to see and even harder to dissolve. So your
   DNA concentration would be too low to get amplification. To prevent
   this measure the concentration of your DNA.
3. It is possible that the water you used is contanminated with DNAses
   (although it shouldn't) and your DNA got degraded by them. Here only
   new aliquots will help.
4. Depending on the size of your amplicon, it is possible that overly
   harsh condition during the preparation led to the shearing of the
   DNA leaving not enough intact DNA to get a proper amplification. If
   this is the case, be more gentle with the extraction.

Additionally your primers can be a problem. It would be good to keep the 100x stock solutions permanently at -20°C and prepare 10x working solutions. These can undergo freezing and thawing (which will degrade them over time) but they can be replaced easily.
I would also try the new DNA prep (if possible side by side with one that is working) with new primers to test if they are the problem.